# How to select a bone in weight paint mode?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I don't know how to select a bone when I am working in *Weight Paint* mode.

How to select a bone when working in another bone at weight paints?

Answer (score 0):

In *Object* mode, select the armature, shift select the object, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, to select a bone use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>, to select a second one use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you sir mush sir

Comment: I am using 2.79verson for practi is it a good move sir

Comment: Hello so does my answer work? I don't remember the shortcuts for 2.7. You'd better switch to Blender 3 if you can

Comment: Yes it works in new version thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

In 2.79 do the following:

1. Select the armature. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch to *Pose Mode* (or alternatively choose it in the modes menu).
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> (if you are using right-click selection in 2.79) to additionally select the object you want to weight paint.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch the object to *Weight Paint* mode (or alternatively choose it in the modes menu).
4. <kbd>RMB</kbd> to select the bone for which you want to paint a weight on the object.

If you switched your Blender to use left-click for selecting in the *3D Viewport*, it can be that maybe you have to use <kbd>LMB</kbd> instead of <kbd>RMB</kbd> (I couldn't test it, my 2.79 crashed when I tried to open the *User Preferences*).